# What is this diff in my go.sum when it has already been checked in this way?

Tags: go, go-modules

I frequently see go.sum changes with this diff:

```
+github.com/owner/pkg v0.0.0-abc h1:$hash
 github.com/owner/pkg v0.0.0-abc/go.mod h1:$hash
```

What is this? Why wouldn't this first line have been part of the commit when the module was initially listed as a dependency? It happens all the time and I am not sure what it even is?

Comment: Are you using multiple different versions of go? The contents of `go.sum` are an implementation detail, and will be consistent within the same version of the go tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line gives the checksum for the *complete source code* for module `github.com/owner/pkg` at version `v0.0.0-abc`.

The second line gives the checksum for the *`go.mod` file only* for module `github.com/owner/pkg` at version `v0.0.0-abc`.

If you have only the second line and not the first, that means that your module's dependencies satisfy the version requirements of `github.com/owner/pkg` at version `v0.0.0-abc`, but nothing you have done so far actually cares about the corresponding source code.

In general, you should find that `go mod tidy` adds or removes the checksum for the source code as needed.

However, note that versions of the `go` command prior to (upcoming) Go 1.16 have a bug in which they also sometimes preserve unneeded checksums for source code. (See https://golang.org/issue/33008 for details.)